# Resolving Vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, geometry

When resolving vectors into their horizontal and vertical components, why must the individual vectors form a closed triangle? I don't understand why vectors must form a closed triangle when one vector is the sum of the other two. Why is this true, and how do prove this?

Comment: Do you mean in the context of a sketch like a force diagram or purely mathematically for the x and y components of the vectors?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751470/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Parallelogram Law of Vector Addition?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751470/)

Comment: The resulting vector (one side of the triangle) must equal the addition of the two vectors when placed tail to head (two other sides). That is how a triangle is formed. Three sides always makes a triangle.